# Python's built in sum function taking forever to compute sums of very large range of values in a list

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension

This works well and returns **249999500000**:

```
sum([x for x in range(1_000_000) if x%2==0])
```

This is slower but still returns **24999995000000**:

```
sum([x for x in range(10_000_000) if x%2==0])
```

However, larger range of values such as `1_000_000_000` takes a very long time to compute. In fact, this returns an error:

```
sum([x for x in range(10_000_000_000) if x%2==0])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
MemoryError.
```

I've seen posts saying that the built-in sum function is the fastest but this doesn't look like being fast to me. My question then is, do we have a faster Pythonic approach to compute large sums like this? Or is it perhaps a hardware limitation?

Comment: of course, you create *a whole list* first. Almost certainly, you are hitting your swap memory, and eventually, simply running out. Don't create a list to find a sum. In this case, you coudl replace it with a generator expression (simply removing the square brackets)

Comment: once you reach numbers like `10,000,000,000` even if each iteration took a microsecond, it would take a couple hours to compute.

Comment: in this particular case, `sum(range(0, 10_000_000_000, 2))` would be much faster. Or of course, you could go for an analytic solution....

Comment: OK I'll try to make the list first and compare. I did this because I wanted to implement sums with fewer lines of code which I thought is a more pythonic way of coding.

Comment: There's no magic here.  `sum` is an `O(N)` function.  If you submit 10 times as many elements, it will take 10 times as long to compute the result.  Just that simple.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to make the list first, it's giving you an out of memory error

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga I did this `sum(range(0, 10_000_000_000, 2))` and even though it still took some time, it's pretty much faster.

Comment: python `range` objects aren't lists. they can be iterated over but they don't literally expand. -- what is the real data? if it's literally just ranges, or slices of ranges, then what's keeping you from using a closed form expression for this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The real idea is to accept 3 values from a user i.e. (the start, stop and step) values and calculate the sum of even and odd numbers in that range of values given by the user. I'll make sure to look at the Gauss sum.

Comment: that's it? then yes, closed form expression and done. just needs some thought put into indices and factors. comparing the closed form expression to any kind of iteration doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz From that Wikipedia article: *"Not to be confused with Triangular Number § Formula"* :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I posted the below code based on the Gauss Sum, Kelly Bundy pointed out a simplification of the math and a practical simplification making use of properties of a `range` object. He suggested I add this here.

An arbitrary range can be visualized as a trapezoid. That there is the sum for the area of a trapezoid.

It also uses the ability of a `range` to know its length. That simplifies my `(stop - start + step-1) // step` expression.

```
def sum_range(*args):
    rg = range(*args)
    return (rg[0] + rg[-1]) * len(rg) // 2 if rg else 0
```

Following is my original answer. I've gridsearched both functions for being identical to `sum_naive`, given argument ranges that cover all the cases.

---

for arbitrary `start, stop, step`:

```
#def sum_naive(start, stop, step): return sum(range(start, stop, step))

def sum_gauss(start, stop, step=1):
    if step == 0:
        raise ValueError("range() arg 3 must not be zero")

    if step < 0:
        step = -step
        shift = 1 + (start - stop - 1) % step
        (start, stop) = (stop+shift, start+1)

    if start >= stop:
        return 0

    # triangle on a base
    n = (stop - start + step-1) // step
    base = start * n
    triangle = n * (n - 1) // 2 * step
    return base + triangle
```

A "geometric" interpretation should make these expressions self-evident. ∎ SCNR

The negative step case is rewritten into a positive step case using equivalent `start` and `stop`.

The sums of even and odd integers in a given range `start, stop` are simply those:

```
one_half = sum_gauss(start, stop, 2)
other_half = sum_gauss(start+1, stop, 2)
# no need to know which are which
assert one_half + other_half == sum_gauss(start, stop, 1)
```

Comment: wow I just tried this and it's incredibly fast

Comment: I need to study this algorithm more for better understanding.

Comment: It works well for large values but it's inaccurate for negative steps. I want it to work for both positive and negative steps. i.e. `range(10, -1, -2)` To accurately find the sum of even numbers and odd numbers in that range of values.

Comment: I did not anticipate the need for negative steps. I'll think about it for a bit.

Comment: negative step, there you go

Comment: works well and incredibly fast. I've marked as answer.

Comment: as for the study of this: it helps me to visualize the numbers as a sequence of bars. -- for this implementation, I tested the code on all possible inputs in the range of -10 to +10, compared the result to the sum of a range. that runs quickly enough and it catches all the cases that need to be handled.

Comment: I'd really have to study this. You are good at what you do. I almost gave up on this but something kept telling me there could be a better fix than the built in sum function.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like my answer doesn't fully address the question and I don't want to repeat that. Would you like to add my implementation to your answer instead? (I'd delete my answer then.)

Comment: sure I can add it with credit but why do you think it doesn't fully address the question? I can see how OP's question is unclear on whether it's really always a range or whether it could be some arbitrary sequence. I believe OP clarified that in a comment somewhere. it really is just ranges.

Comment: Yes, because of that uncertainty of whether it's always a range.

Comment: Btw the way I think of the formula: Write the sequence twice - once forwards, and below that, backwards. The vertical pairs first+last, second+secondToLast, ..., last+first  all have the same sum. And we have len(rg) pairs, so total sum is (first+last)\*len. And then we need to divide by 2 because we wrote the sequence twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you're trying to pre-compute all of the even numbers and putting them in a list, instead of using generators. To change your list comprehension into a generator, simply replace `[]` with `()`, and this way you don't eat up all of your memory. The branching there is kind of stupid as well when you can use the `step` input of `range`.
Finally like Tangentially Perpendicular said, you can use a mathematical formula to calculate the same thing but be careful of floating point errors when using large numbers, so stick to integer math only (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77527507/take-an-integer-num-as-input-using-input-function-write-a-program-to-find-the-s) for more details).

Possible solutions and a quick benchmark:

```
def sum_of_evens(n):
    num_evens = (n+1)//2
    return num_evens*(num_evens-1)

n = 10_000_000
print(sum((x for x in range(n) if x%2==0))) # 1.09 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
print(sum((x for x in range(0,n,2)))) # 394 ms ± 14.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
print(sum_of_evens(n)) # 288 ns ± 42.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

needless to say: iterating over billion(s) of elements will be slow, no matter what, so you can't hope for better runtime than solution #2 if you want to actually iterate over the numbers, but the memory problem can easily be solved.

Comment: *"you can't hope for better runtime than solution #2 if you want to actually iterate over the numbers"* - Sure you can. Simply ditch the generator, have `sum` iterate the `range` directly.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the `range()` function creates a long list of integers which `sum()` then has to add up. For short lists this will work, but the execution time is roughly proportional to the length of the list. Double the length of the list and double the execution time.

Of course, you could be a bit more intelligent than that.

Using Gauss's formula:

```
def gauss(a, b):
    return (a + b)/2*(b-a+1)

a = int(input('Enter 1st number: '))
b = int(input('Enter 2nd number: '))

print(f'Sum of {a} to {b} is {gauss(a, b)}')
```

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917510/gauss-formula-to-add-number-of-sequence-for-arbitrary-range) on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: your solution only works for small numbers, but not for the kind of numbers that the OP is using as it relies on floating point math.

Comment: This works only for sums of consecutive integers. OP's code computes the sum of even numbers, so the formula will be a bit different.

Comment: Gauss Sum is exactly the right idea. Getting the rest of it right is just exercise.

Comment: as for the "floating point" point, it's incorrect to claim that this answer *relies* on floating point math. it's simply an accident of implementation (choice of operator). the math is identical.

Comment: @bb1 My bad. Doubling Gauss's formula will give the sum of even numbers. Halve the range to get the correct result for the question. I'll add this to the answer later.

Comment: @OM222O Strictly speaking, the arithmetic depends on the implementation of the language, so for Python you're correct. There is nothing to prevent one performing calculations using some arbitrary precision library that avoids that issue.

Comment: Python already does arbitrary-size arithmetic for integers. he only refers to your choice of `/`(instead of `//`) for the division, which causes the arithmetic to come out as floating point.